# What exactly IP-adresses Android system check to say "No internet connection"?

Tags: android

today my ISP lost connectivity to all (sic!) Google services, so my Android phone is constantly saying "No internet" for my WiFi.

But everything else besides Google is accessible from my laptop on the very same WiFi. So the question is: what exactly IP addresses Android is checking to say if there is an internet connection?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63481/how-does-android-determine-if-it-has-an-internet-connection

Comment: It's more like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/glf3xf/connectivitycheckgstaticcom_why/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the answer is: *connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204*

Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-avoid-the-captive-portal-checkin-to-google.3927561/